# Error al tratar de ejecutar un archivo de MP3 en C#

Tags: c#

Quiero ejecutar un archivo .MP3 en mi aplicación de C#, pero siempre que se ejecuta el método de `timerson`, me aparece un error que me indica que ***WindowsMediaPlayer está en uso***.

No se cómo cerrar la instancia o matar ese proceso ya que no me deja continuar en mi código.

Este es el código actual:

```
public void timerson()
{
    MessageBox.Show("Cada cierto tiempo segundos");
    WindowsMediaPlayer myplayer = new WindowsMediaPlayer(); -- Error
    myplayer.URL = @"C:\Users\david\Music\Cancion.mp3";
    myplayer.controls.play();
}

public void ejecutar()
{
    var timer = new System.Threading.Timer(
        e => timerson(),
        null,
        TimeSpan.Zero,
        TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0.3));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías dejar la clase instanciada y simplemente jugar con la misma instancia del reproductor:

```
class Clase
{
    WindowsMediaPlayer myplayer;

    public Clase()
    {
        myplayer = new WindowsMediaPlayer();
    }

    public void timerson()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Cada cierto tiempo segundos");
        myplayer.controls.Stop();
        myplayer.URL = @"C:\Users\david\Music\Cancion.mp3";
        myplayer.controls.play();
    }

    public void ejecutar()
    {
        var timer = new System.Threading.Timer(
            e => timerson(),
            null,
            TimeSpan.Zero,
            TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0.3));
    }
}
```